# editor.codeActionsOnSave does not run in order: changes form VSCode 1.82 to VSCode 1.83

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to preserve the order when I save data, in version 1.82 I could use:

```
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
    "source.addMissingImports",
    "source.organizeImports",
    "source.fixAll.eslint"
  ],
```

but not working in version 1.83

I need to use:

```
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.addMissingImports": "always",
    "source.organizeImports": "always",
    "source.fixAll.eslint": "always"
  },
```

The question is: Does VSCode 1.83 respect the order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the same issue: [breaking: codeActionsOnSave](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194861):

> I would like to apply format and sorting before the lint. With the
> object configuration, it is not possible anymore.

You can subscribe to the issue and add your use case (although it is very similar to the case presented there already).  But it appears it is already being worked on by a vscode team member.

---

There is a PR already on the issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194957

If possible, you might test it in the Insiders Build starting 10/05/2023.  Looks like the previous array version would be supported again as well as possible fixes for the object version.